# Writing a 16bit bytearray in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays

I'm trying to write the following 16bit WAV header data into a 16bit bytearray.  Does anyone know how to achieve this? I am using actionscript 3.

52 49 46 46 54 00 13 00 57 41 56 45 62 65 78 74 5A 02

---

What I'm doing is trying to pass the correct bytearray to this mp3 encoder (http://code.google.com/p/flash-kikko/) to get it to write out an mp3. If I use their example, I can open a 16bit WAV file via filereference and pass in that bytearray to the encoder to export an mp3. But, I want to create my own bytearray and pass it in and create the mp3. Using HxD, I copied the header and footer of that same 16bit WAV file and pasted it into flash as a bytearray, but when I pass it into the encoder, it freezes the compile and I get the following error:

```
  Error #1502: A script has executed for longer than the default timeout period of 15 seconds.
```

So, I think my issue is with how I'm formatting the bytearray that I'm passing in... any ideas? Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want all 18 bytes (your question says 16 bits)?

```
var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
byteArray.writeByte(0x52);
byteArray.writeByte(0x49);
byteArray.writeByte(0x46);
```

etc. Just follow the pattern for the remaining 15 bytes.

Each of the two digits you show, for example, "5A" actually represents a byte in hexadecimal. The 0x is needed to tell Flash you're using hex values -- otherwise, AS3 will think you're using decimal.

Comment: I'm trying to pass the correct bytearray to the mp3 encoder (code.google.com/p/flash-kikko/) to get it to write out an mp3. If i use their example, i can open a 16bit WAV file via filereference and pass in that bytearray to the encoder to export an mp3... but i wanna create my own bytearray and pass it in and create the mp3. Using HxD, i copied the header and footer of that same 16bit WAV file and pasted into flash as a bytearray but when i pass it into the encoder, it freezes the compile and i get the error- A script has executed for longer than the default timeout period of 15 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Why not automate tedious job...

```
var header:String = "52 49 46 46 54 00 13 00 57 41 56 45 62 65 78 74 5A 02";

var headerParts:Array = header.split(" ");
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

for each (var s:String in headerParts)
{
    bytes.writeByte(parseInt(s, 16));
}
```

Now bytes contains your header.